# Laravel - pluck mutated attribute

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have run into an issue, and it is really only a minor inconvenience, but...

Basically what I need is an associative array for a select box. Normally, this would be achieved using the `pluck()` function.

The problem is, the attribute that I want to use as the 'text' does not actually exist in the database, it is a mutator that combines two fields into one.

```
public function getNameAttribute() {
    return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
}
```

I know that adding the `'name'` field to the `$appends` array on the model will include that field when casting the model to array, however this does not seem to work with `pluck()`

Is there a simple way to achieve want I want? Function or declaration I'm missing? Anything more eloquent than manually looping over the collection and creating my own associate array?

**Update**

I'm an idiot. I was passing an array to pluck instead of two parameters. Apparently pluck does utilize the `$appends` attribute. Note, this only works when working with collections:

```
$collection->pluck('mutatedValue', 'key');
```

**NOT** the query builder

```
$queryBuilder->pluck('mutatedValue', 'id');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can dynamically append the attribute to the objects in your collection:

```
$users->each(function ($model) { $model->setAppends(['name']); });
$users->pluck('name');
```

This has the nice advantage of not requiring `'name'` always be part of your array data, while allowing your collection to use `name` just in time.

Comment: Turns out I didn't need to do this after all, but +1 so far for a somewhat elegant answer.

Answer (score 31):

I was looking for an answer to this and ended up with a different result so I thought I'd share.

```
User::get()->pluck('name');
```

If you get the object first, your mutated attribute will be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You can query with eloquent and use

```
$limited_select = User::all(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name']);
$limited_select = array_flip($limited_select);
```

I assumed you wanted to prevent a `select *` when possible.

generating the select you can do something like this in blade:

```
<select>
    @foreach($limited_select as $user)
        <option value={{$user->id}}> {{$user->getNameAttribute() }} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

This would work because `getNameAttribute()` inside your `User Model` wil act as an accessor.

Your second option could be using a raw query that has a concat, but I think the eloquent way is more elegant.

Comment: That would unfortunately not provide the results I expect. The pattern I am looking for is ```$array as $id => $name```. What you have provided would result in ```$array as $index => $attributes``` I would still need to loop over the collection and modify the results before using them.

Comment: array_flip would not work with multi-dimensional arrays. each ```$attributes``` would be an array ```['first_name => 'Example', 'last_name' => 'Guy']``` testing this results in the following error ```array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values!```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `collection` method such as `map()`:

```
<?php
    // ...

    User::get()
        ->map(function($user) {
            return [
                'id'    => $user->id,
                'text'  => $user->myCustomAttribute
            ];
        })
        ->pluck('text', 'id')
        ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Many of people are really missing this.

You should get the mutated fields first before plucking them like so:

```
$results = Model
  ::where('field', 'value')
  ->get(['first_name', 'last_name', 'id'])
  ->pluck('mutatedValue', 'id');
```